# logged out immediately after successful login

Tags: reactjs, rest, session, authentication, logout

I have developed an application using `reactjs` and `rest` services. Now I want to add an login and logout option for the user . I have created successfully created the login page and when I click the login button it redirects to the main page and logout immediately.

I have cleared the local storage also.

```
logout() {
localStorage.clear();
window.location.href = './login';
}
```

Can I know where it went wrong?

```
      <Button href="#" onClick={this.logout()}>LOGOUT</Button>
```

Comment: remove `()` here: `onClick={this.logout}`, otherwise logout function will get executed during rendering of this page without click on that button.

Comment: you can do like that
logout = () => { some text here }

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you have used a **function call** instead of passing a function reference.

When passing handlers down to the child components you must be passing a **reference** not **function call**

**Change**

```
<Button href="#" onClick={this.logout()}>LOGOUT</Button>
```

**To**

```
<Button href="#" onClick={this.logout}>LOGOUT</Button>
```